# How can I get the log of a TestFlight app from xcode

Tags: ios, react-native, logging, app-store-connect, testflight

I am building a react native app and I would like to see the logs of a release build in ios.

Is it possible to get the console.log of a TestFlight app from xcode, like in development mode?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Do you mean to plug your iphone into mac and see the logs or do you mean running a release version on your iphone through xcode and seeing the logs?

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Murmeltier. I want to see the log on a release version. I tried to install the release version on an iPad Mini but I have not managed to do it so far. I get a error message saying that the app cannot be installed because of an invalid provisioning profile. I tried several things but nothing worked.

Comment: So testflight is there, but not able to install on a physical device... Did you add your iPad  mini to your provisioning profile? Back to topic: no you can't see the logs on your device if you install a compiled app.

Answer (score 1):

You can't get a console.log of a testlfight app, because it's already distributed and disconnected from the XCode. What you can do is test it directly on the Xcode itself by building and running it when it works accordingly, then distribute it to testflight.

Comment: True, however I do not believe this is possible when testing push notifications.